# How can I list random authors from current post category?

Tags: posts, categories, functions, author, list-authors

The following lists authors of the current category.
But I want this to be a list of 6 random authors from current post category.

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
  $postcat= $category->cat_ID;
 }

$current_category_ID = $postcat;
$current_cat_id = $current_category_ID;
$author_array = array();
$args = array(
'numberposts' => -1,
'cat' => $current_cat_id,
'orderby' => 'author',
'order' => 'asc',

);
$cat_posts = get_posts($args);
foreach ($cat_posts as $cat_post) :
if (!in_array($cat_post->post_author,$author_array)) {
$author_array[] = $cat_post->post_author;
}
endforeach;
foreach ($author_array as $author) :
$auth = get_userdata($author)->display_name;
$auth_link = get_userdata($author)->user_login;
$autid= get_userdata($author)->ID;
$link = get_author_posts_url($autid);
echo ''. get_avatar( $autid, '46' ).'';
echo "<a class='sidebar-aut' href='$link";
echo "'>";
echo '<h6>'.$auth.'</h6>';
echo "</a>";
echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>";
echo "<br />";
endforeach;
```

Comment: Can, did I interpret it right: "list of 6 random authors"? I'm not quite sure because the code you're trying `$category_detail=get_the_category($post->ID)` doesn't make much sense... Maybe what you need are PHP functions: [**`suffle`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) and [**`array_slice`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php).

Comment: I update my code, im listing right now, just i need random 6 or any number list author.

Comment: I forgot to comment: *please*, add indentation to your code, it's easier to read, for you and for us. ::::: Did you look at the PHP functions?

Comment: I will pay attention to it..Yes but i never used it before and insufficient knowledge of my php. 'shuffle($author_array)' this do random but how can i list any number author(e.g just 6 author) :)

Answer (score 0):

After you populate `$author_array`, you need to pick 6 random users out of it. Here are two straightforward choices:

1. Shuffle the array `shuffle($author_array);` and pop values off of it in a for or while lopp using `array_pop()`
2. Create a randomized copy of six elements of the array using `array_rand($author_array,6);` and then iterate through the new randomized array using foreach as you did above.

Personally I prefer #2, but please note that if you try to pick 6 random elements from an array of fewer than 6 elements with `array_rand()` you'll get a warning. You'd want to test the size of `$author_array` with `count($author_array)` first to either limit your `array_rand()` command to the max size of the potential list of authors, or to skip it entirely if it's 1.

Something like, after your first foreach ends:

```
if(count($author_array) >= 6) {
    $max = 6;
} else {
    $max = count($author_array);
}

$random_authors = array_rand($author_array,$max);
foreach ($random_authors as $author) { ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try with your code, but same author listing always and looped didnt stop. I did try with the following code and i want to share with maybe you can advise me. Before shuffle and later call first 5 element. Code: 'shuffle($author_array); $author_rnd= array_slice ($author_array , 0, 5);'